# Dropdown default values return null?

Tags: html, jsp, default-value

I have html in my JSP which ask simple questions, as well as having drop-down boxes for users to select their responses. I also set default responses as well incase they decide to just hit next however I always get null returned. JSP:

```
<div id="startQrtQuestion" align="left">1) When did you first arrive here?</div>
        <div id="startQrtResponse" align="left">
            <select name="quarterStart">
                <option value="summer">Summer Quarter</option>
                <option value="fall" selected="selected">Fall Quarter</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <div id="programQuestion" align="left">2) What program are you taking?</div>
        <div id="programResponse" align="left">
            <select name="programSelect">
                <option value="bscs" selected="selected">BSCS</option>
                <option value="bstm">BSTM</option>
                <option value="bsgd">BSGD</option>
                <option value="bswd">BSWD</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="extendedQuestion" align="left">3) Will you be staying extra quarters?</div>
        <div id="extendedResponse" align="left">
               <div name="extendedStayResponses">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="extendedStay" id="extendedStay"/>Yes
               </div></br>
               <div id="extendedFullTime" style="display:none">
                   Full Time:<select name="extraFullQuarters">
                       <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4</option>
                       <option value="5">5</option>
                       <option value="6">6</option>
                       <option value="7">7</option>
                       <option value="8">8</option>
                       <option value="9">9</option>
                       <option value="10">10</option>
                   </select>(Taking 12 Credits or More)
               </div></br>
               <div id="extendedPartTime" style="display:none">
                   Part Time:<select name="extraPartQuarters">
                       <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4</option>
                       <option value="5">5</option>
                       <option value="6">6</option>
                       <option value="7">7</option>
                       <option value="8">8</option>
                       <option value="9">9</option>
                       <option value="10">10</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
        </div>
```

This is all wrapped in a form that will call the post method in my servlet. However when I retrieve those values like so:

```
    String startQuarter = request.getParameter("quarterStart");
    String programSelect = request.getParameter("programSelect");
    String extendedStay = request.getParameter("extendedStay");
```

I get null pointer exceptions. Is the value not automatically set to what I have as my default selected option?

Am I not accessing these inputs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it wasn't any of this code. But another set of code in my group's project.

It turned out to be a session attribute that's suppose to be set, but isn't.

Comment: I can't mark it as answered until 2 days from now. :( If anyone has the power to do so please let it be.

Answer (score 0):

it might be your request object is null.Check it once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up finding it by doing so. The request object wasn't null. But a session attribute that suppose to exist is. But is it alright if I give PLR the points since his suggestion ended up helping me find the problem.